# How can I make an Asynchronous image download center for UITableViewCells?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, asynchronous, uiimage

I want to asynchronously download lots of UIImages from websites and place them in a tableView. But instead of using classes already out on the web, I would like to make my own. What is needed to do this, what callbacks should I use, and what api would be best to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLConnection and delegates are your best bet.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd encourage you to take a look at the [EGOImageLoading](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading) library.

It has the ability to load images asynchronously, displays placeholder images, can cancel requests when the view disappears while the fetch is in progress, implements an image cache and provides an UIImageView subclass to take advantage of these features.

*EGOImageLoading* uses the following API's / classes:

- NSURLConnection
- NSOperationQueue
- Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)
- NSFileManager
- Property Lists